# How can I put just Newspaper Name and City in Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, memoir, biber, biblatex-chicago

Currently each newspaper citation goes into the Bibliography as a separate entry. Is it possible to set it up that the `\autocite` command will put the exact article in the footnote but instead of an entry into the bibliography for each article can just put one entry per newspaper used be entered.

For example in the case of the following MWE the entries in the bibliography would look like below even though I cite three separate articles from The Times.

> *Evening Post*, Wellington
>
> *The Times*, London
>
> *The Sydney Morning Herald*, Sydney

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text
\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, includeall=true,]{biblatex-chicago}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{EPost1,
Entrysubtype = {magazine},
address = {Wellington},
journal = {Evening Post},
keywords = {NP, primary},
date = {1915-12-11},
pages = {5},
title = {article title}}

@article{Bloggs1919,
Entrysubtype = {magazine},
address = {London},
author = {Bloogs, Joe},
journal = {The Times},
keywords = {NP,primary},
date = {1919-10-24},
pages = {8},
title = {Joes News}}

@article{Doe1919,
Entrysubtype = {magazine},
address = {London},
author = {Doe, John},
journal = {The Times},
keywords = {NP,primary},
date = {1919-02-19},
pages = {10},
title = {Roundup by John}}

@article{Times1,
Entrysubtype = {magazine},
address = {London},
journal = {The Times},
keywords = {NP,primary},
date = {1921-02-09},
pages = {9},
title = {Read all about it}}

@article{SMH1,
Entrysubtype = {magazine},
address = {Sydney},
journal = {The Sydney Morning Herald},
keywords = {NP,primary},
date = {1920-09-16},
pages = {9},
title = {The News Today}}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname} 

\begin{document}


\lipsum[1]\autocite{EPost1}

\lipsum[1]\autocite{Bloggs1919}
\lipsum[1]\autocite{Doe1919}
\lipsum[1]\autocite{Times1}
\lipsum[1]\autocite{SMH1}

\backmatter

\printbibheading
\nobibintoc %prevents showing sub-bibs in toc
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\parsep}
\printbibliography[keyword=NP,heading=subbibliography,%
title={Newspapers}]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can live with a reference entry formated slightly differently than you had imagined, this can be quite simple. Namely, if the standard formatting for `magazine` entrysubtype is acceptable for you in the bibliography. That is:

> *Journal title* (Location).

Within these requirements, you can achieve the desired results only rearranging your bib entries with standard biblatex facilities, particularly `crossref` and `options`.

You can create entries for the newspapers as a whole, and then use `crossref` to link individual articles to them (in the process saving some typing, as the `journaltitle` and `location` are then inherited by the individual article).

For the individual articles, there are several ways to omit them from the bibliography. You seem to be screening by `keywords`, I've chosen here `options = {skipbib=true}` (and thus let go with your former keywords for individual articles). But, of course, you could also arrange the same effect with a suitable set of keywords as well.

Notice I added the option `mincrossrefs=1` to the call of biblatex (the default is 2). That means a single crossref citation will trigger the entry in the bibliography.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text
\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, includeall=true, mincrossrefs=1]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{EPost1,
Entrysubtype = {magazine},
date = {1915-12-11},
pages = {5},
title = {article title},
crossref = {EveningPost},
options = {skipbib=true}}

@article{Bloggs1919,
Entrysubtype = {magazine},
author = {Bloogs, Joe},
date = {1919-10-24},
pages = {8},
title = {Joes News},
crossref = {TheTimes},
options = {skipbib=true}}

@article{Doe1919,
Entrysubtype = {magazine},
author = {Doe, John},
date = {1919-02-19},
pages = {10},
title = {Roundup by John},
crossref = {TheTimes},
options = {skipbib=true}}

@article{Times1,
Entrysubtype = {magazine},
date = {1921-02-09},
pages = {9},
title = {Read all about it},
crossref = {TheTimes},
options = {skipbib=true}}

@article{SMH1,
Entrysubtype = {magazine},
date = {1920-09-16},
pages = {9},
title = {The News Today},
crossref = {SydneyMorningHerald},
options = {skipbib=true}}

@article{EveningPost,
Entrysubtype = {magazine},
journaltitle = {Evening Post},
location = {Wellington},
keywords = {NP, primary}}

@article{TheTimes,
Entrysubtype = {magazine},
journaltitle = {The Times},
location = {London},
keywords = {NP, primary}}

@article{SydneyMorningHerald,
Entrysubtype = {magazine},
journaltitle = {The Sydney Morning Herald},
location = {Sydney},
keywords = {NP, primary}}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname} 

\begin{document}


\autocite{EPost1}

\autocite{Bloggs1919}

\autocite{Doe1919}

\autocite{Times1}

\autocite{SMH1}

\backmatter

\printbibheading
\nobibintoc %prevents showing sub-bibs in toc
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\parsep}
\printbibliography[keyword=NP,heading=subbibliography,%
title={Newspapers}]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

If you really need the newspapers formated as:

> *Journal title*, Location.

in the bibliography, then more structure may be required, as I had initially supposed.

Comment: Ya, _Journal title_ (Location) will be fine.